# Error when performing Server-Sent Events

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli, server-sent-events

Good evening all,
I wanted to try out the server-sent event. I want to show

```
NEW ATTACK FROM SINGAPORE TO MALAYSIA
```

This is just an example.

I created a php script to make an array full of countries and then access any one country from the `array`. After that I `echo` the data. I use event source to stream data from the PHP script... However, i am not able to see anything on the `HTML` page. Instead, the PHP script is executing again again again in the network tab

[image]

When i observe the event stream in network tab, the data is empty

I followed the code from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse), and tried it out. I think I did not miss anything..
My code is found below..

**shownewattack.php Code:**

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$countryarr = array("UNITED STATES", "INDIA", "SINGAPORE","MALAYSIA","COLOMBIA","THAILAND","ALGERIA","ENGLAND","CANADA","CHINA", "SAUDI ARABIA");
$length = sizeof($countryarr);
$random = rand(0,$length);
$random1 = rand(0,$length);
$random_srccountry = $countryarr[$random];
$random_dstcountry = $countryarr[$random1];
echo "[x] NEW ATTACK: FROM [".$random_srccountry."] TO [".$random_dstcountry."] \n\n";
flush();
?>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("shownewattack.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**My question** is why is there no output on my page though the script is executed multiple times. Can you please fix this problem??? Thank you

Comment: First of all, `array_rand()` doesn't work the way you expect. But that doesn't not explain why you don't get output. Hold on, let me test your code.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, your `shownewattack.php` always stays the same, because of the `array_rand()` mistake, and hence never generates an event. There's also the missing `$` in front of the country array.

Comment: can you elaborate more about the mistake which you are referring to???

Comment: Read the manual, `array_rand()` returns keys, not values.

Comment: After learning that i made the mistake, i use random rather than the array_rand() to generate number from 0 to the length of the array. I run the php script, it work. However, it does not appear in the html page

Comment: I want to see the data in the html page rather than the network tab. I am going to update my code

Comment: We do mind. Please recognize that other people use SO as a resource to find solutions to their problems. So, either post your solution, or remove the question.